# There is a way to block scroll in a specific section of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page have many sections and I wanted to know if it's possible make the page scroll up and down just in that section.

```
<body>
<section id="1"><!-- if you are here then you can scroll down-->
some huge text<!--if you reaches the end of the text you can't scroll down anymore-->
<a href="#2">section2</a><!--but if you click the link you can scroll down to section2-->
</section>
<section id="2">
some huge text
<a href="#3">section3</a>
</section>
<section id="3">
some huge text
<a href="#3">section4</a>
</section>
</body>
```

If you are you are in the section1 you can scroll up and down just in section 1, but, if you click in a link you can scroll up and down in the section 2 and the section 1, but, you still can't go to section3 before you click in the another link. There is some way to do something like that?

Comment: Define block scroll. Do you mean like this? http://www.dominikgorecki.com/p/block-scroll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You could also try implementing iScroll.
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

```
.mainBody
{
  height: 40rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4
{
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}

<body>
    <div class="mainBody">
        <section id="section1"><!-- if you are here then you can scroll down-->
            some huge text<!--if you reaches the end of the text you can't scroll down anymore-->
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            <a href="#section2">section2</a><!--but if you click the link you can scroll down to section2-->
        </section>
        <section id="section2">
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text 
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            <a href="#section3">section3</a>
        </section>
        <section id="section3">
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            <a href="#section4">section4</a><!--but if you click the link you can scroll down to section2-->
        </section>
        <section id="section4">
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text 
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            some huge text
            <a href="#section1">section1</a>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create new HTML page for each section, for example page1.html, page2.html, page3.html and then put that in your href.

Or alternatively you can only display one section at a time and then when clicking on the link hide/show other sections.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you could move each block on a click and have each block as a scrollable div. You could add in animations so it scrolls nicely when you click next/previous. You could also accomplish this in plain javascript if you wanted.

**HTML**

```
<div class="section active">
  Text 1<br>
  ...
</div>
<div class="section">
  Text 2<br>
  ...
</div>
<div class="section">
  Text 3<br>
  ...
</div>
<div class="section">
  Text 4<br>
  ...
</div>
<div id="prev">
Previous
</div>
<div id="next">
Next
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html{
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
.section{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.section.active{
  top: 0;
}
.section.prev{
  top:-100%;
}
#prev, #next{
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#prev{  
  left: 10px;
  display: none;
}
#next{
  right: 10px;
}
#next:hover, #prev:hover{ background-color: #444; }
```

**JS**

```
var page = 1;
var lastPage = $('.section').length;

$('#next').click(function(){
    page++;
  $('#prev').show();
  if(page >= lastPage){
    $('#next').hide();
  }
  $('.section').eq(page-2).addClass('prev').removeClass('active');
  $('.section').eq(page-1).addClass('active');
});
$('#prev').click(function(){
    page--;
  $('#next').show();
  if(page == 1){
    $('#prev').hide();
  }
  $('.section').eq(page).removeClass('active');
  $('.section').eq(page-1).addClass('active').removeClass('prev');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h99s94rf/

### Pure JS

```
var $ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
var id = document.getElementById.bind(document);
var page = 1;
var lastPage = $('.section').length;

id('next').addEventListener("click",function(){
    page++;
  id('prev').style.display = 'block';
  if(page >= lastPage){
    id('next').style.display = 'none';
  }
    //add class prev
    if ($('.section')[page-2].classList)
    { $('.section')[page-2].classList.add('prev'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page-2].className += ' ' + 'prev'; }
    //remove class active
    if ($('.section')[page-2].classList)
    { $('.section')[page-2].classList.remove('active'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page-2].className = $('.section')[page-2].className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + 'active'.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' '); }
    //add class active
    if ($('.section')[page-1].classList)
    { $('.section')[page-1].classList.add('active'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page-1].className += ' ' + 'active'; }
});
id('prev').addEventListener("click",function(){
    page--;
  id('next').style.display = 'block';
  if(page == 1){
    id('prev').style.display = 'none';
  }
  //remove class active
    if ($('.section')[page].classList)
    { $('.section')[page].classList.remove('active'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page].className = $('.section')[page].className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + 'active'.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' '); }
    //remove class prev
    if ($('.section')[page-1].classList)
    { $('.section')[page-1].classList.remove('prev'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page-1].className = $('.section')[page-1].className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + 'prev'.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' '); }
    //add class active
    if ($('.section')[page-1].classList)
    { $('.section')[page-1].classList.add('active'); }
    else
    { $('.section')[page-1].className += ' ' + 'active'; }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h99s94rf/1/

Comment: It's preferable to do this with javascript, because i want it to work offline, and doesn't seems jquery will work.

Comment: @ELS I've added a pure JS solution that should work on IE9+ and all modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#element').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
})
```